# I installed Ubuntu 22.10 on the partition where I had Fedora 37

Tags: boot, grub-efi, 22.10, fedora

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 on the partition where I had Fedora 37. It still shows Fedora logo on boot and when I hold shift it opens Fedora's GRUB menu. I have to go to Boot options to open Ubuntu. How do I fix this and remove every single element of Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `os-prober` that generally seeks out the names of the operating system is disabled by default in newer versions of Grub, but you can re-enable it by editing your Grub configuration file.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file with elevated permissions:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
   ```
3. Save the configuration file and exit your editor of choice
4. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot to confirm that everything is good

This change was made starting with Ubuntu 22.04.